# Cannot download file from external url

Tags: php, html

I use amazon s3 cloud storage.
I've created a code that generates the link of the file that I call by name.
So url calling is working fine.
but when i try to download it by a button in html. It doesn't start downloading.

Here is my code

```
 <a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" class="btn btn-outline-dark" style="width:150px;" >Download Now</a>
```

As you see  $url generates. and works fine. but when i click on the button.
It doesn't start downloading. So when I copy the link and paste in a new browser tab, it starts downloading.

[Here is test link of my code](https://d1.landof3d.com/index.php?filekey=1decorations/vase/Set%20of%20decorative%20ceramic%20vases.rar&server_id=1)

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: No HTML works fine. I'm not getting any errors. @j08691

Comment: you should edit your question and add more detailed code: php, html and js, better if you give us a code snippet that reproduce the undesired behavior

Comment: I have added a test page. can you check. @Lety

Comment: Neither by click nor by copying link it works, I got time-out, sorry I don't know why. I could be a problem on server side.